# Scala: Traversable foreach definition

Tags: scala, generics

I suppose `foreach` method in `Traversable` trait is defined as follows:

```
def foreach[U](f: Elem => U)
```

Should it be defined as `foreach[U,Elem](f:Elem =>U)` as there are two types, `Elem` and `U` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foreach[U](A => U)` is a method in the trait `Traversable[+A]`.

```
trait Traversable[+A] extends TraversableLike[A, ...] {
  ...
}

trait TraversableLike[+A, ...] extends ... {
  ...

  def foreach[U](f: A => U): Unit

  ...
}
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableLike.scala#L124

Answer (score 3):

The `Elem` type comes from the generic type of the `Traversable`.  The input to the function must the the same type as the elements of the `Traversable` so it doesn't make sense to redefine it at the method call site.