# What does the A mean in the def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B?

Tags: scala, generics, type-parameter

The `foldLeft` and many other collection methods of the Scala library will have the method signature like this
`def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B`.

I know the type parameter `B` means the result type of the binary operator. But I have no idea what does the type parameter `A` mean, it does not even allude that in the documentation. I feel confused!

Comment: `A` is the element type of the collection this `foldLeft()` is being called on. Example: `List(1,2,3).foldLeft(...`, `A` is `Int`. Example: `Array('a','b','c').foldLeft(...`, `A` is `Char`. It's a kind of silent assumption in the documentation.

Comment: Note that `A` is documented in the [documentation](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html). At the top of the page, the collection has a signature such as `sealed abstract classList[+A]` and it's said: `A class for immutable linked lists representing ordered collections of elements of type A.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46835288/scala-traversable-foreach-definition/

Answer (score 0):

foldLeft is a function for the collection type. So A means the element type in the collection.

For example:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).foldLeft[Int](0)((a, b) => a + b)
```

b is Int type, value is the element of "1,2,3"